# Getting data from large number of lists and processing it - heap space error

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory, weak-references

I have my data in a data structure like this:

```
List <List<Long>> data;
```

And I have say thousands of such lists with 10's to hundreds of elements in each list. I need to process each list at a time and create objects out of it to be stored into a file on hard disk.
I am using a loop iterator like:

```
for(List <Long> chunk : data) {
   process(chunk);
   writeTofile(chunk);
}
```

But I am getting OutOfMemory error of Java heap space. I checked the heap using Eclipse Memory Analyzer and it is saying memory leaks due to weak references. Also the process(chunk) function is an exponential function for the size of chunk.

Is it that new memory space is created for every chunk in data.size() or same space which was used by data.get(1) is now utilized for data.get(2)?
Any help to overcome that?
Is the following code any different in terms of memory utilization?:

```
List <Long> chunk;
for(chunk : data) {
   process(chunk);
   writeTofile(chunk);
   chunk.clear();
}
```

Are arrays any better tool when it comes to efficient garbage collection? I have used -Xmx11g to run this program. please advice. Thanks

Comment: The error that you are getting must be pointing to some portion in your code. What you are doing there ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `chunk` list need more space after calling `process(chunk)`. It looks like you're having enough memory for all `data` before processing, but not thereafter. So clearing the chunk upon use seem to be the right solution. Usually, using arrays instead of collections is a bad idea: Arrays are the old low-level stuff mostly useful as building blocks of collections.

If you have many very short collections, then switching to arrays may be profitable. Also in your case when dealing with primitives. The memory consumption of `List<Long>` may be something like three times the memory consumption `long[]` of the same size. You can sort of have both comfort of collections and compactness of arrays by using e.g. [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) primitive collections.